# getting data from webpage with select menus with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, select, html-parsing

I am trying to collect data from a webpage which has a bunch of select lists i need to fetch
data from. Here is the page:- http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/

And this is what i have so far:

```
import glob, string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, csv

for file in glob.glob("http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/*"):

##-page to show all selections for the E-series-##
selected_list = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/'

##-
page = urllib2.urlopen(selected_list)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

##-page which shows results after selecting one option-##
url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B'


##-identify the id of select list which contains the E-series-##  
select = soup.find('select', id="myselectListModel")
option_tags = select.findAll('option')

##-omit first item in list as isn't part of the option-##
option_tags = option_tags[1:]

for option in option_tags:
    open(url + option['value'])


html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all = soup.find('div', id="accordion")
```

I am not sure if i am going about the right way? As all the select menus make it confusing. Basically i need to grab
all the data from the selected results such as images,price,description,etc. They are all contained within
one div tag which contains all the results, which is named 'accordion' so would this still gather all the data?
or would i need to dig deeper to search through the tags inside this div? Also i would have prefered to search by id rather than
class as i could fetch all the data in one go. How would i do this from what i have above? Thanks. Also i am unsure about the glob function too if i am using that correctly or not?

**EDIT**

Here is my edited code, no errors return however i am not sure if it returns all the models for the e-series?

```
import string, urllib2, urllib, csv, urlparse from bs4 import
BeautifulSoup


##-page which shows results after selecting one option-##
url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B'


base_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/' + url

print base_url

##-page to show all selections for the E-series-##
selected_list = urllib.quote(base_url + '/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B')
print urllib.quote(base_url + '/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B')

#selected_list = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series/ET10B'

##-
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All%20In%20One/E%20Series')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print soup

##-identify the id of select list which contains the E-series-##  
select = soup.find('select', id="myselectListModel")
option_tags = select.findAll('option')

print option_tags 

##-omit first item in list as isn't part of the option-##
option_tags = option_tags[1:]

print option_tags


for option in option_tags:
    url + option['redirectvalue']

print " " + url + option['redirectvalue']
```

Comment: What is with the `for` loop that you put in there? You need to fix th e indentation, showing what belongs in the loop and what doesn't.

Comment: `glob()` only works for local files, it does *not* work for URLs. You'd need some other means to find out what pages exist at that site, and that probably involves parsing.

Comment: please take a look at my edited code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to point out a couple of problems you have in the code you posted. First, of all the `glob` module is not typically used for making HTTP requests. It is useful for iterating through a subset of files on a specified path, you can read more about it [in its docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

The second issue is that in the line:

```
for file in glob.glob("http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/*"):
```

you have an indentation error, because there is no indented code that follows. This will raise an error and prevent the rest of the code from being executed.

Another problem is that you are using some of python's "reserved" names for your variables. You should never use words such as `all` or `file` for variable names.

Finally when you are looping through `option_tags`:

```
for option in option_tags:
    open(url + option['value'])
```

The `open` statement will try and open a local file whose path is `url + option['value']`. This will likely raise an error, as I doubt you'll have a file at that location. In addition, you should be aware that you aren't doing anything with this open file.

Okay, so enough with the critique. I've taken a look at the asus page and I think I have an idea of what you want to accomplish. From what I understand, you want to scrape a list of parts (images, text, price, etc..) for each computer model on the asus page. Each model has its list of parts located at a unique URL (for example: http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/Desktop/B%20Series/BM2220). This means that you need to be able to create this unique URL for each model. To make matters more complicated, each parts category is loaded dynamically, so for example the parts for the "Cooling" section are not loaded until you click on the link for "Cooling". This means we have a two part problem: 1) Get all of the valid (brand, type, family, model) combinations and 2) Figure out how to load all the parts for a given model.

I was kind of bored and decided to write up a simple program that will take care of most of the heavy lifting. It isn't the most elegant thing out there, but it'll get the job done. Step 1) is accomplished in `get_model_information()`. Step 2) is taken care of in `parse_models()` but is a little less obvious. Taking a look at the asus website, whenever you click on a parts subsection the JavaScript function [`getProductsBasedOnCategoryID()`](http://www.asusparts.eu/Scripts/zandparts/js?v=YEJnEnHMMK5v1D40Pe9UcnsBMOM5DeunIn3eJdVuiVY1) is run, which makes an ajax call to a formatted `PRODUCT_URL` (see below). The response is some JSON information that is used to populate the section you clicked on.

```
import urllib2
import json
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/'
PRODUCTS_URL = 'http://json.zandparts.com/api/category/GetCategories/'\
               '44/EUR/{model}/{family}/{accessory}/{brand}/null/'
ACCESSORIES = ['Cable', 'Cooling', 'Cover', 'HDD', 'Keyboard', 'Memory',
               'Miscellaneous', 'Mouse', 'ODD', 'PS', 'Screw']


def get_options(url, select_id):
    """
    Gets all the options from a select element.
    """
    r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    select = soup.find('select', id=select_id)
    try:
        options = [option for option in select.strings]
    except AttributeError:
        print url, select_id, select
        raise
    return options[1:]  # The first option is the menu text


def get_model_information():
    """
    Finds all the models for each family, all the families and models for each
    type, and all the types, families, and models for each brand.

    These are all added as tuples (brand, type, family, model) to the list
    models.
    """
    model_info = []

    print "Getting brands"
    brand_options = get_options(BASE_URL, 'mySelectList')

    for brand in brand_options:
        print "Getting types for {0}".format(brand)
        # brand = brand.replace(' ', '%20')  # URL encode spaces
        brand_url = urlparse.urljoin(BASE_URL, brand.replace(' ', '%20'))
        types = get_options(brand_url, 'mySelectListType')

        for _type in types:
            print "Getting families for {0}->{1}".format(brand, _type)
            bt = '{0}/{1}'.format(brand, _type)
            type_url = urlparse.urljoin(BASE_URL, bt.replace(' ', '%20'))
            families = get_options(type_url, 'myselectListFamily')

            for family in families:
                print "Getting models for {0}->{1}->{2}".format(brand,
                                                                _type, family)
                btf = '{0}/{1}'.format(bt, family)
                fam_url = urlparse.urljoin(BASE_URL, btf.replace(' ', '%20'))
                models = get_options(fam_url, 'myselectListModel')

                model_info.extend((brand, _type, family, m) for m in models)

    return model_info


def parse_models(model_information):
    """
    Get all the information for each accessory type for every
    (brand, type, family, model). accessory_info will be the python formatted
    json results. You can parse, filter, and save this information or use
    it however suits your needs.
    """

    for brand, _type, family, model in model_information:
        for accessory in ACCESSORIES:
            r = urllib2.urlopen(PRODUCTS_URL.format(model=model, family=family,
                                                 accessory=accessory,
                                                 brand=brand,))
            accessory_info = json.load(r)
            # Do something with accessory_info
            # ...


def main():
    models = get_model_information()
    parse_models(models)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Finally, one side note. I have dropped `urllib2` in favor of the `requests` library. I personally think provides much more functionality and has better semantics, but you can use whatever you would like.

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I have tried it out this way but it is being a pain saying that it can't find the module requests even though i installed it, so i reverted back to using the old way as that is how the tutor wants it to be.. they frown upon different methods even though they are better -_- Anyway, i gathered i would need to create a unique URL for each model however, shouldn't the `for option in option_tags:
    url + option['redirectvalue']` take care of this? Also i have changed my code but i am not sure if it is gathering all the models for the E-Series

Comment: Happy to help. You can change requests back to urllib2 pretty easily, simply replace every instance of `requests.get()` with `urllib2.urlopen()` and replace `r.json()` with `json.load(r)` (you will need the json module). You're right that you could directly obtain the URL from the redirectvalue. The reason I didn't is that I realized you do not need the model's URL to get the products. You need to know the (brand, type, family, model), and storing that information as a URL just means more string formatting. I've edited my answer to use urllib2 instead of requests.

Comment: Ahh ok..cheers. I forgot to mention about you adding a products url from the sister site, zand parts which confuzzled me- is this necessary?